# Save image from URL to device with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Hi as title suggests I need to save images to Android device from my CDN.

I am building app with React Native, and what I've done is that:

`fetch('https://server.com/images.json').then((json) => console.log(json))`

Which returns json:

`{images: ["cdn.server.com/image1.jpg", "cdn.server.com/image2.jpg"]}`

And now I really don't know what to do to save images to my device, because then I need to use them to open Instagram Intent (https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/) and it only works if image is saved to device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know react can using Java code.

I offen using this code to get image from url.

```
String imageCDN = json.getString("images");
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);

imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageCDN, imgflag);
```

But you should [read this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html)
At this code:

```
renderMovie(movie) {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
      style={styles.thumbnail}
    />
    <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
```

You don't need to save image because memory leak, using ListView to clone all image in DataSource.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but one thing. To start Instagram Intent I need to pass URI to image, e.g. file:///tmp/image.jpg. Can it temporary point to that file, so that Instagram intent opens correctly?

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis I posted your question in: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7072. You try this link: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs